# ¿como o con que ejecuto la ruta o funcion de una aplicacion web autonamente?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, firebase

tengo un sistema o dispositivo que envia unos dato a la base de datos, cuando esos datos llegan tengo una función que los ejecuta y envía otros datos en respuesta a la base de dato. la pregunta es, ¿como puedo hacer que esa funcion se ejecute siempre sin necesidad de tenerla abierta en un navegador y sin necesidad de un usuario lo haga? eso lo hago para detectar rutas mediante googlemaps api
estoy trabajando con angular, firebase y la API de googlemaps

Comment: Alexander, bienvenido a so, por favor, intenta subir el código que tienes para poder ayudarte. Saludos. PD: Para ayudarte en la formulación de preguntas, te recomiendo esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Lo quenentiendo es que cuando se guarda en la base de datos necesitas que internamente y automáticamente se ejecute una función como para dar aviso de que fue recibido o guardado con éxito ?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo estás intentando ejecutar una función en Firebase sin interacción del usuario. Lo más sencillo sería sería implementar una tarea programada (cron) en tu servidor y que llame a una URL expuesta por un [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) para hacer lo que hoy haces a mano ya que las funciones hoy en día no soportan tareas programadas.

Dejo un artículo que explica una manera de [hacerlo usando Google Cloud](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html), aunque se puede hacer con cualquier servidor que pueda hacer un llamado a una dirección HTTP.